# Let $X_1, ... , X_5$ be a random sample from $p(x;\theta)=(1-\theta)^{x-1}\theta$. Find the UMPT size $\alpha = 0.1$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_5$ be a random sample from $p(x;\theta)=(1-\theta)^{x-1} \theta$, for $x=1,2,3,\ldots$. Consider $H_0:\theta \geq 0.7\text{ vs. } H_1:\theta<0.7$. Find the UMPT size $\alpha = 0.1$.

My try: let $$H_0^{'}:\theta_0 = 0.7\text{ vs. } H_1^{'}:\theta=\theta_1 \quad(\theta_1<0.7)$$

Now, using the NP Lemma $$\frac{L(\theta_1)}{L(\theta_0)} = \frac{(1-\theta_0)\theta_1^n(1-\theta_1)^{\sum ^5_{i=1}x_i}}{(1-\theta_1)\theta_0^n(1-\theta_0)^{\sum ^5_{i=1}x_i}}\geq k$$

Then I end up with $$\sum ^5_{i=1}x_i\geq c$$

Then $$\Psi^*(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&\sum ^5_{i=1}x_i\geq c\\
0&\sum ^5_{i=1}x_i< c.
\end{cases}$$

In order to find alpha, I need to know the probability distribution of $\sum ^5_{i=1}x_i$ but I'm not sure how to do this or if my method is correct. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Looks good! For the next step, do you recognize the probability distribution and know its generalization? Or you know how to use moment generating functions?

Comment: I don't recognize it. I know that it must be a discrete distribution (maybe binomial). Any hints?

Comment: you should look into the negative binomial and the geometric distributions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application of the Neyman-Pearson lemma looks good. To complete the problem, you need to identify the distribution of $Y = X_1 + \cdots+ X_5$. Notice that $X_i$ counts the number of Bernoulli trials until a success, so that $Y$ counts the number of trials until you get $5$ successes. To get $P(Y=y)$, we simply need to count:

1. Observe that the $y$-th Bernoulli trial must be a success
2. In the previous $y-1$ trials, we must have observed $4$ successes and $y-5$ failures; there are ${y-1 \choose 4}$ ways in which these trials can happen

Hence, for $y \geq 5$,
$$P(Y=y) = {y-1 \choose 4} \theta^5 (1-\theta)^{y-5} $$
This distribution is sometimes called the negative binomial distribution.